# requires one of dependencies in Perl

Tags: perl, dependencies, dependency-management

What's the best way to handle a Require dep A or dep B in Perl? I'm thinking about converting some of my [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) modules to use [Any::Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Any%3a%3aMoose). But this creates the problem that I will a require either [MooseX::Types](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aTypes) or [MouseX::Types](https://metacpan.org/module/MouseX%3a%3aTypes). I use [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla). What's the best way to go about handling this?

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, you may want to have a look at the way [JSON::Any](https://metacpan.org/source/PERIGRIN/JSON-Any-1.29/Makefile.PL#L11) handles this.

Also, Any::Moose tackles a similar problem while using dzil.  See its [dist.ini](https://metacpan.org/source/SARTAK/Any-Moose-0.18/dist.ini#L20) and [Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/SARTAK/Any-Moose-0.18/Makefile.PL#L27).  You could maybe also have a look at dynamic_config in [CPAN::Meta::Spec](https://metacpan.org/module/CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec#dynamic_config)

Comment: is [Module::Install](https://metacpan.org/module/Module::Install) really the only/best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Good point -- it was really just the first thing I thought of.  You did mention Any::Moose and, after looking at that, I think you could draw some inspiration there, so I've added that above.